# How to to make sure file permissions descend in Google Drive

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, directory

I'm trying to write a script that takes the current editors of a folder and changes their permission to view only only at the lowest level folders. Everything is working fine, except it seems that it is taking Google Drive too long to apply the permissions of the top folder (View only) to all of the sub folders. Because of this, the editors of TOP_FOLDER, who originally had Edit access to all of the sub folders since it was inherited from TOP_FOLDER, retain this access when I run the script even though when I preform the exact same action in Drive they all have View only access after I refresh the page.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

```
function fixFilePermissions() {

  var oldEditors = TOP_FOLDER.getEditors();

  TOP_FOLDER.addEditors(ADMINS);

  //remove All but the admins
  for each (var editor in oldEditors){
    //if editor is not an admin
    if(ADMINS.indexOf(editor) < 0){
      //remove editor
      TOP_FOLDER.removeEditor(editor);
      //add back as viewer
      TOP_FOLDER.addViewer(editor);
    }
  }

  recFixFilePermissions(TOP_FOLDER);

}


function recFixFilePermissions(folder){

  while(folder.getEditors().length > ADMINS.length){
    Utilities.sleep(200);
    Logger.log(folder.getEditors().length - ADMINS.length);
  }

  Logger.log("Folder: "+folder.getName());
  Logger.log("Editors: "+folder.getEditors());
  Logger.log("Viewers: "+folder.getViewers());


  if(folder.getFolders().length > 0){

    for each (subfolder in folder.getFolders()){
      recFixFilePermissions(subfolder);
    }

    Logger.log("Has Subfolder");    

  }else{

    for each (var person in folder.getViewers()){
      folder.addEditor(person);
      Logger.log("Gave " + person + " Edit Access to " + folder.getName());
    }
  }

}
```